# Declaring slf4j logger only in superclass/abstract class and using it in all child classes is good practice?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

Declaring slf4j logger only in superclass/abstract class makes content of child classes clearer (no clutter of sth like `private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tuple5x36.class);` mess).

Is such practice recommended, or there are significant pitfalls?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With this approach in logs all your messages will belong to your superclass, so you won't be able to distinguish them by ancestor, only by message itself.
So i would suggest to have a separate logger instance for each class.

Comment: wrote the same thing few seconds behind you. Sorry. Upvoted.

Answer (score 8):

I don't see any pitfall. Declare it as such in your superclass:

`protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());`

I believe most, if not all, implementations of getLogger() return singleton objects from a map. So there's no benefit in declaring loggers static -- even though almost everyone does -- other than to avoid a call to getLogger() upon instance construction. But since that call is fast, the benefit is essentially non-existent. (And not declaring them static has the benefit of making them easy to mock for unit tests.)

Answer (score 1):

The pitfall is that call to `LoggerFactory.getLogger(Tuple5x36.class)` creates a logger which is namespaced as the fully qualified name of the class used to create it.

In other words this call creates a logger placed within `com.package.to.Tuple5x36`. It will be that name which will appear in log entries from all children classes, so you will have a trouble (or perhaps no way of) distingishing which actual class logged.

You also cannot change the logging level for a single inheriting class, but for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing neither as the first suggests that the log message comes from the abstract class even if it doesn't and the second is indeed mess.

Add "lombok" to your dependencies and then just annotate every class with @Slf4j to get a "private Logger log" variable available.